# Not sure how to call method with a collection return type with variables

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I'm not sure what collection type to use, but I was thinking that a Dictionary would be best for this. I need to be able to create Key Value Pairs and I'd like to be able to iterate over it, preferably with a foreach loop. The tricky part is that I'd like to be able to pass in the key and value (both strings) when I call the method and store them into the collection to use later.

I was thinking something like this:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DictionaryTest("this","that");
    }

public static void DictionaryTest(Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary)
{
    testDictionary.Add(string, string);


    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> fields in testDictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fields.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(fields.Value);
    }


}
```

The trouble is, I'm not sure how to set the key value strings up as variables to use. Also, I'm not even sure that using a Dictionary is the way to go here, but I do know that I won't have a fixed number of entries in the collection and that I want to pass all of the key, value pairs to another method later on which are basically used as search fields and search values.

In general, I'd like some advice and possible direction to help guide me here. More of a question about methodology as much as it is about syntax.

Thanks

Update: I ended up doing it this way...

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        DictionaryTest("this","that");
    }
public static Dictionary<string,string> DictionaryTest(string Key, string Value)
{

    Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    testDictionary.Add(Key,Value);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> fields in testDictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fields.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(fields.Value);
    }

    return testDictionary;

}
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking. From what you've written a dictionary seems appropriate. "I'm not sure how to set the key value strings up as variables to use" Not sure what that means.

Comment: Basically, when I call the method, I'd like to be able to put the key,value strings in the method arguments. If you look at the DictionaryTest method, I'm trying to .Add() to the collection, but I'm not sure how to use variables there so that I can just pass the key and value strings in when I call the method. I'm not sure I'm explaining this very well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adjusted your code to what I think you're asking:

```
//you ever need a class wide variable to hold your dictionary, or you need to make a new one in the Main method 
static Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DictionaryTest(myDict, "this","that"); //you didn't pass a dictionary object when you called this method
}

public static void DictionaryTest(Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary, string keyToAdd, string valToAdd) //you didn't have parameters for the strings you passed when you called this method
{
  testDictionary[keyToAdd] = valToAdd; //same as Add(), but doesn't crash on dupe

  //I generally iterate dictionaries by iterating the keys collection and accessing the dictionary whenever I need to, rather than accessing a collection of keyvaluepair
  foreach (string key in testDictionary.Keys)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    Console.WriteLine(testDictionary[key]);
  }


}
```

It's not the only way to do things.. Many times in coding the way it is done is preference rather than rule, and it is influenced by how the client wants things to work. Don't take this code as a hard and fast rule of how you must do things, it's just one way that works

Adriani6 made a good point about your confusion in the original code:

`Dictionary<string, string>` simply means "a dictionary whose key is a string and whose value is a string". It's an entire type of object on its own, different to (for example) `Dictionary<int, string>` - these things are no more the same type than Customer and Order are in the classic sales system. Generics are one of those things where the compiler writes a bunch of code for you before it compiles, meaning the generic Dictionary becomes one dedicated for just string,string (and another totally separate one as int,string for example) - the compiler actually writes a lot of code for us, to make various features of the language work and give us a simpler cleaner syntax to work with than the early days where all this stuff had to be literally written by us humans.

When you stated that your `DictionaryTest` method took a single parameter of type Dictionary, then tried to pass it two strings, C# won't think "oh, the method asks for a double stringed dictionary, and two strings are being passed, obviously I'll use them as the key and the value.." because it can't for several reasons:

- where does it get the actual dictionary object from, to use these strings with?
- which one is the key and which is the value?
- method resolution purely looks at the type and order of arguments passed, it doesn't look at the types that are stored inside objects and guess. Here's another example:

  ```
  class Person{
    string Name;
    int Age;
    bool IsMale;
  }

  ...
  public void RegisterPerson(Person p) //a method 


  ...

  RegisterPerson("John", 31, true);
  ```

The RegisterPerson method takes a Person object, c# cannot accept you passing a bunch of primitive types that effectively make up a person, and auto make a person for you and pass it to the method.. you can do it explicitly with

```
RegisterPerson(new Person(){ Name = "John", Age = 31, IsMale = true });
```

Or you can define an overload that takes primitives and makes a new person:

```
public void RegisterPerson(Person p){ ... }
public void RegisterPerson(string name, int age, bool IsMale) {
  RegisterPerson(new Person(){ Name = name, Age = age, IsMale = IsMale});
```

It's just that c# won't do this for you. Hopefully you can see how this also applies to your dictionary situation

Comment: So I think I figured out that the best way to do this is actually to create the Dictionary object in the Main method and in the test method, I'm actually just passing 2 strings in as the arguments and then using them in the actual DictionaryTest method. I'm oversimplifying it for the sake of learning how to apply some rules, but I think it would work in other cases>

Comment: You don't need to make a dictionary in main AND in test, and if you get into the habit of doing that then your programs aren't going to work very well,  cause the idea of having a data storage container is that you don't always make a new one every time you try to put stuff in it :) see my edits to my answer for some other points..

Comment: Ah ok, I see what I did wrong. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the comments it seems that your issue is that you don't understand the type that the `DictionaryTest` method expects. It expects a Dictionary, what you get confused about is the `<string, string>` part. That indicated that the key as well as the value is expected as a string, not any other format.

For a cleaner example:

`Dictionary<key type, value type> variableName`.

So to work this out, what you need to do is create a dictionary to pass in as an argument.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DictionaryTest(new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"this","that"}});
}
```

Note, I created a Dictionary object with a single value inside of it, key: this and value: that.

Comment: I was clear about the fact that the dictionary needed string types for both the key and the value, what I didn't know how to do was to set the actual string values as a variable instead of an actual value, but I figured out that I actually needed to set the method parameters as strings and pass them in when I call the method instead of passing in an actual dictionary.